# Merging a Diamond and Hexagon Shape in CSS?

Tags: html, css

With the website I am working on one of the features is reviews.
I want to create a `polygon` that is a merge of a Hexagon and Diamond.
Similar to the logo of the website.

[Here is an example.](https://jsfiddle.net/Rane_MstSage/u41tgbyx/4/)

```
<div class="release-image-score-wrapper">
 <span class="release-image-score-hexagon">
  <span class="border-hexagon">
   <span class="shadow-cover"></span> 
  </span>                
 </span>                
<div class="release-image-score-text">9</div>              
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's an awfully complex thing to do in CSS... why not simply use a background image?

Comment: Either use background image as suggested by @ObsidianAge, or use SVG. Why waste your time on the code, when you can simply create a SVG, or background image.

Comment: try to provide at least a sketch of what you have in mind, dont let other people guess what you want.

Comment: @ChrisLi Thank you, that was why I provided the fiddle and logo. Using one of the answers I was able to tweak it to what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the logo, here it is, this might help you. Pure CSS version of that logo.

```css
.logo {
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:white;
  border:2px solid black;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
}
.logo::after {
  content:'';
  width:27px;
  height:27px;
  background-color:white;
  position:absolute;
  border: 1.5px solid orange;
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-color: white;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
}
.logo::before {
  content:'';
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background-color:white;
  position:absolute;
  border:2px solid orange;
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-color: white;
  z-index:1;
  top:4px;
  left:3px;
}
span {
  width:16px;
  height:17px;
  border:1px solid black;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  top:6px;
  left:5px;
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-color: white;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  font-size:12px;
  text-align:center;
  color:orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="logo">
    <span>M</span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think he need hexagon, please see to it if you can put any square inside a hexagon that will do the answer.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar He asked similar to logo,

Comment: yes you are right, but i think there is hexagon also on the example provided (on tom raider image). Anyway, i think these two solutions will help the user get his answer.

Comment: I already have the SVG snippet. The idea was to use divs to create the review score backdrop. So a hexagon with a diamond overlay (see logo in jsfiddle) is what I am trying to achieve. I could always do it with a background image, but I wanted to see if this would work first.

Comment: Just to be clear this is similar to what I want, however I want to fill it and add a shadow to the hexagon and inner diamond. Then the score would go in the center.

Comment: I want to thank you, I was fiddling with this and got it to do exactly what I wanted. https://jsfiddle.net/Rane_MstSage/2tk9hdm3/

Comment: @RaneMstSage my pleasure, I am happy that it helped you